# Updating linux kernel broke my computer

Tags: kernel, boot

Today I updated the linux kernel to 4.8.12-2 using `pacman -Suy`. Next time I tried to turn on my computer, I got the following error:

```
Starting vmlinuz-linux
Using load options 'ro root=UUID=1d7....... initrd=\initramfs-linux.img'
EFI stub: ERROR: Failed to read file
Trying to load files to higher address
EFI stub: ERROR: Failed to read file
```

Using an arch live usb, I backed up `/boot/vmlinuz-linux` and installed version 4.8.11-1. Now, when I try to boot, only the lts version shows up in the rEFInd submenu (both lts and non-lts used to show up). When I try to edit `/boot/EFI/refind/refind.conf`, I get an input/output error.

Please help me. I am totally lost at this point. Just hoping my laptop isn't lost.

Comment: Chroot in, make sure `/` and `/boot` are mounted, and rerun the upgrade. In all likelihood, `/boot` was not mounted during your last upgrade.

Comment: @jasonwryan `/boot` was definitly mounted. If it were not, wouldn't the upgrade have had no effect anyway?

Comment: No, it would have just installed the kernel to the wrong place, which would lead to the situation you are describing.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. My exact commands were `mount /dev/sda1 /mnt; mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/boot; arch-chroot /mnt; pacman -Suy`

Answer (score 1):

Somehow, my esp got corrupted. After backing everything up and running S.M.A.R.T. tests to make sure it wasn't a hardware issue, I reformatted the esp and reinstalled rEFInd:

```
 mkfs.fat -F32 /dev/sda2
 refind-install --usedefault /dev/sda2
 cd /var/cache/pacman/pkg
 pacman -U linux-4.8.12-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz
 mkinitcpio -p linux
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. When system update was running, my laptop suddenly turned off (I have no idea why), and when I tried to boot it I saw the same message. I fixed it this way: I booted from rescue flash drive. Then:

1. `wifi-menu` - enable wifi network.
2. `mount /dev/sda2 /mnt`
3. `arch-chroot /mnt`
4. `mount -o rw /dev/sda1 /boot`
5. `cd /var/cache/pacman/pkg`
6. `pacman -U linux-4.8.12-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz`

Package was reinstalled. It notified me that there were problems with some file and they were fixed. After that I closed session and unmounted all drives and rebooted. System boots ok now.

Answer (score 0):

[Just found out that `EFI stub: ERROR: failed to read file.`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/46f4582e7cbc5f30127183812d4da875782518f5#diff-c9082e9a20336aef99c84e788c363034R475) (at least in my case) actually refers specifically to `initrd` (which had been nuked by an unplanned shutdown during updates).

someone changed the message to 'generalize' the code at some point.